# Javascript pass a global variable to a function to feed value

Tags: javascript

I have a global variable that I am passing into a function. The function should feed/generate some values to that variable. So far, I tried:

```
var final_transcript = "";
function test1(x) {
  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    x += event.results.transcript;
  }
}

StartButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  test1(final_transcript);
})

EndButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(final_transcript);
})
```

In this case, assuming `StartButton` is clicked before `EndButton`. So the `StartButton` initiate the function that feeds in strings that add into the global variable `final_transcript`. when `EndButton` is clicked, the variable `final_transcript` should contain all the strings fed in. But the value of `final_transcript` is still empty according to the console log.

EDIT: recognition.onresult transcript the user's voice into text. It is a real-time event.

The reason why I am doing this is that the function `test1` cannot detect an end event. Only `EndButton.addEventListener` does, and I cannot add it in `test1` function.

Comment: what is recognition.onresult?

Comment: The answer is covered by this SO post:  [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Why not have your functions return values instead.